# Convert radians to degree / degree to radians

Tags: r, math, degrees, radians

Are there build-in functions in R for the conversion of radians to degree and degree to radians?

So far I wrote my one own functions:

```
rad2deg <- function(rad) {(rad * 180) / (pi)}
deg2rad <- function(deg) {(deg * pi) / (180)}

#test:
rad2deg(pi) #180
rad2deg(2*pi) #360
deg2rad(180) #pi
```

Comment: `install.packages("sos", dependencies = TRUE); library(sos); findFn("convert degree to radian")`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The comment of Pascal was very useful and I found several ones, e.g.

```
install.packages("NISTunits", dependencies = TRUE)
library(NISTunits)

NISTdegTOradian(180)
NISTradianTOdeg(pi)
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `units` package for this.

```
library(units)
pi_rad <- as_units(pi, "radians")
pi_deg <- set_units(pi_rad, "degrees")
set_units(pi_deg, "radians")
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a data.frame It could help you

In my case davis_2$wd is the column in degree

```
#Add column to Data Base
davis_2$radian_wd = davis_2$wd

#Create a loop to change the data, and change the 62'th col to Radians
for(i in 1:nrow(davis_2)){
    davis_2[i, 62] = (davis_2[i, 62]*pi)/180
}
# Review
head(davis_2$radian_wd)
```

Comment: It's unnecessary to write a loop: `davis_2$radian_wd <- (davis_2$radian_wd*pi)/180` is enough